# iPad app: Enterprise-wide distribution without UDIDs?

Tags: ipad, deployment, distribution

I developed an iPad app for a donation campaign and want to distribute it to the iPads now. Since several iPads are effected, I dont wanna create a provisioning profile for each single iPad.

On the website: http://mdmclient.net I can easily download&install the app's plist file without giving them my iPads UDID.

So with other words, is it possible to distribute the app without registering all the UDIDs?!
I would like to avoid buying an enterprise license/account due to the limited amount of money of the donation campaign (I'm developing the app for free for them)...

Or do you think I can only install the app from http://mdmclient.net because they are using an enterprise profile/account?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to distribute an app to many iPads without registering every device's UDID is an enterprise developer account. The guys at MDM Client seem to have an enterprise account.

So basically there are 2 ways you can go:

1. Distribute your app via the AppStore.
2. Purchase an enterprise developer account.

Or there is a third way (of course that's probably too late now, as your app is already finished): Do it as a HTML web app.